# Using startActivity outside an Activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I am inside a class that doesn't extends an Activity and I am trying to access the method startActivity and also MainActivity to make an intent, like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity, MusicasPlaylistActivity.class);
PlayList item = (PlayList) adapter.getItem(position);
intent.putExtra("id", item.getId());
startActivity(intent);
```

But inside my class I cannot see the method "startActivity" and I cannot see "MainActivity" neither because my class doesn't extends an Activity because it already extends another class (called RecyclerView.ViewHolder).

How can I access the startActivity method and the MainActivity to make the intent?

Comment: you must have the context of your activity there so use it like `context.startActivity` plus use this `Intent(context, MusicasPlaylistActivity.class);`

Comment: you must use callback/listener to do this. Don't call start activity outside of context. Use this

https://gist.github.com/chowii/0e87e75b06e217b380ae5482b7c06c8e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I access the startActivity method and the MainActivity to make
>   the intent?

you need a `Context` object for that. You can either pass it to the constructor or, in your case, use `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` `itemView` to retrieve it. E.g.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), MusicasPlaylistActivity.class);
PlayList item = (PlayList) adapter.getItem(position);
intent.putExtra("id", item.getId());
itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

`itemView` is the `public final View` hold by `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`

Comment: this is a bad practice, if you are trying to do anything relating to a view or context do it there. Have the activity or fragment call MusicasPlaylistActivity not your ViewHolder. To do that you need a callback. Don't call start activity outside of context. Use This as a guide

gist.github.com/chowii/0e87e75b06e217b380ae5482b7c06c8e

Answer (score 1):

In your class Constructor pass context like this:

```
public class YourClass{
  private Context context;
  public YourClass(Context context){
     this.context = context;
  }
}
```

then

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity, MusicasPlaylistActivity.class);
PlayList item = (PlayList) adapter.getItem(position);
intent.putExtra("id", item.getId());
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

simply get the context of acivity. then call.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(yourcontext, MusicasPlaylistActivity.class);
PlayList item = (PlayList) adapter.getItem(position);
intent.putExtra("id", item.getId());
yourcontext.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you are defining 'goToMusicasPlaylistActivity()' method in a non-activity class.

```
public void goToMusicasPlaylistActivity(Context ctx) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, MusicasPlaylistActivity.class);
  PlayList item = (PlayList) adapter.getItem(position);
  intent.putExtra("id", item.getId());
  ctx.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Context.
In your class constructor, you can initialize yourcontext.

```
PlayList item = (PlayList) adapter.getItem(position);
intent.putExtra("id", item.getId());
yourcontext.startActivity(intent);
```